# Three arff files majority voting

Tags: java, api, machine-learning, weka

I have three different ARFF files that contain different classification information about the same instances, so that each line of each ARFF file concerns the same instance, but contains different information on that instance. I would like to build a new classifier that would have a majority vote on the three classifiers that would applied on each ARFF data file with a cross validation

Any clue or hint is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic proposition, based that you would use Java to train and evaluate your ensemble:

- Prepare each of the three datasets according to their attribute requirements, or if possible, use the same dataset for all three models using an attribute filter for each classifier (never tried this)
- Train each of the three classifiers using the required training/attribute data
- Code the Majority Vote rules at the end of your evaluation process
- Evaluate your model on your Testing Set.

There may be other ways to do this (such as using the Vote combiner with AttributeSelectedClassifier), but doing this by code may give you more control and flexibility for what you are trying to combine.